# Dynamic load external modules in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have `node.js` application that host an angular2 application. The whole application is using lazy loading like this:

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '', component: MyComponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'lazy',
                loadChildren: '../common/lazy/lazy.module#LazyModule'
            }
    }
]
```

The other team in my company is building another kind of software, but we want to reuse some of their modules. We don't want to share strictly code base, but rather host a module publicly and let it load by the application itself so we can do something like this

```
export const externalRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'externalModule',
        loadChildren: 'http://mymodules.host/lazy.module#LazyModule'
    }
]
```

Is is possible to load module in "live" application? I know there's something like dynamic component loader, but we need to load a module with plenty of components in it.

Comment: This might be helpful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42093101/angular2-with-typescript-how-to-use-plupload-cdn-script-file-in-lazy-loaded-mod

Comment: do you use angular cli? do you want to load a router module?

Comment: Not yet, my goal is to use aot later. I want to use lazy-loading to load a module from external source (using http//mydomain.com/module). This module could be compiled js? Perfect solution would be to use dynamic routes and that this module could be attached with its own children routes. For example on /externalModule, I grab the module from http//externalMdoule and this module adds a children routing to allow to access /externalModule/page1 /externalModule/page2 where page1 and page2 are components downloaded with the module

Comment: Did you resolved? @zagubionytroll

Comment: @user3757628 unfortunately not

Answer (score 0):

You can't load a module out side of your project for security reasons.

What you can do it, as the other team to create a Angular Library project

https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries

and consume it as a module by adding it as a dependency in **package.json**