# ASP.NET Identity, persistent cookie - is something like this build in?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, asp.net-identity

We are using **CookieAuthenticationProvider** and would like to implement the **'Remember me'** functionality in our application that would work like this:

1. No matter if the **'Remember me'** checkbox is checked or not, **the token expiration time should always be set to 30 minutes** (with SlidingExpiration turned on)
2. If user doesn't check 'Remember me' all we do is check if token expired - if it did, then user is redirected to login screen (this is build in into OWIN and works fine)
3. However if user checks 'Remember me' his credentials should be saved in the **additional** cookie (with default lifetime of 30 days). If his token expires (the timeout should still be set to 30 minutes), **OWIN should use that additional cookie to renew the token automatically in the background**. So in other words - if user check 'Remember me' he should be logged in for 30 days or until he logs out.

Question is - how can something like this be done with OWIN? As far as I can see, the default implementation still uses **ExpireTimeSpan** parameter - the only difference is, that the cookie is marked as persistent, so if user restarts browser he is logged in - but token expiration is still limited by ExpireTimeSpan.

I guess I have to somehow manually save user credentials during the **SignIn** and override the **OnApplyRedirect** event (that seems to be the only event fired if an unauthorized user tries to access a view that requires authorization), and instead of redirecting, somehow regenerate user's token... but does anybody know how exactly to do that?

Comment: See [ASP.NET Identity Remember Me](http://sftool.blogspot.com/2016/01/aspnet-identity-remember-me.html) and [MVC 5 ASP.NET Identity 2: Capture user's preference for “remember me” in ExternalLogin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23279259/mvc-5-asp-net-identity-2-capture-users-preference-for-remember-me-in-externa)

Comment: BTW - *never* store your user credentials in a cookie!! Use a token instead.

Comment: @NightOwl888:

Thanks for the links and sorry for the late response - using this: https://coding.abel.nu/2014/06/writing-an-owin-authentication-middleware/ as a guideline, I'm trying to understand how all of this works two questions however

1. Am I correct to assume that in the end no password (or other sensitive data) should be saved in additional cookie but only user Id and claims

2. Could you elaborate what did you mean about using the token instead of cookie? I thought that OWIN encrypts authentication data and thus there is no difference where we save it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I ended up writing custom middleware and plugging it in:

**RememberMeTokenMiddleware.cs:**

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using WebApplicationtoRemove.Owin.HelperClasses;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;

namespace WebApplicationtoRemove.Owin.Middleware
{
    public class RememberMeTokenMiddleware : OwinMiddleware
    {
        #region Private Members

        private static double RememberMeTokenPeriodOfvalidityInMinutes = 43200;

        private IOwinContext Context { get; set; }

        #endregion

        #region Public Static Members



        #endregion

        #region Constructor

        public RememberMeTokenMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next)
            : base(next)
        {
        }

        public RememberMeTokenMiddleware(OwinMiddleware next, double RememberMeTokenPeriodOfvalidityInMinutes)
            : base(next)
        {
            RememberMeTokenMiddleware.RememberMeTokenPeriodOfvalidityInMinutes = RememberMeTokenPeriodOfvalidityInMinutes;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Public Methods

        public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                Context = context;

                bool shouldDeleteRememberMeToken = CheckIfRememberMeTokenShouldBeDeleted(context);

                if (shouldDeleteRememberMeToken)
                {
                    context.Response.Cookies.Delete("RemoveRememberMeToken");

                    context.Response.Cookies.Delete("RememberMeToken");
                }
                else
                {
                    if (context.Authentication.User == null || !context.Authentication.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                    {
                        //User is either not set or is not authenticated - try to log him in, using the RememberMeCookie
                        Login(context);
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Something went wrong - we assume that cookie and/or token was damaged and should be deleted
                context.Response.Cookies.Delete("RememberMeToken");
            }


            await this.Next.Invoke(context);
        }

        #endregion

        #region Static Methods

        /// <summary>
        /// Check conditions and creates RememberMeToken cookie if necessary. This should be called inside SidnedIn event of CookieProvider
        /// </summary>
        public static void CheckAndCreateRememberMeToken(CookieResponseSignedInContext ctx)
        {
            try
            {
                bool signedInFromRememberMeToken = CheckIfUserWasSignedInFromRememberMeToken(ctx.OwinContext);

                if (!signedInFromRememberMeToken && ctx.Properties.IsPersistent)
                {
                    //Login occured using 'normal' path and IsPersistant was set - generate RememberMeToken cookie
                    var claimsToAdd = GenerateSerializableClaimListFromIdentity(ctx.Identity);

                    SerializableClaim cookieExpirationDate = GenerateRememberMeTokenExpirationDateClaim();

                    claimsToAdd.Add(cookieExpirationDate);

                    var allClaimsInFinalCompressedAndProtectedBase64Token = GenerateProtectedAndBase64EncodedClaimsToken(claimsToAdd);

                    ctx.Response.Cookies.Append("RememberMeToken", allClaimsInFinalCompressedAndProtectedBase64Token, new CookieOptions()
                    {
                        Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(RememberMeTokenPeriodOfvalidityInMinutes)
                    });

                    //Remove the SignedInFromRememberMeToken cookie, to let the middleware know, that user was signed in using normal path
                    ctx.OwinContext.Set("SignedInFromRememberMeToken", false);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //Log errors using your favorite logger here
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// User logged out - sets information (using cookie) for RememberMeTokenMiddleware that RememberMeToken should be removed
        /// </summary>
        public static void Logout(IOwinContext ctx)
        {
            ctx.Response.Cookies.Append("RemoveRememberMeToken", "");
        }

        #endregion

        #region Private Methods

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns information if user was signed in from RememberMeToken cookie - this information should be used to determine if RememberMeToken lifetime should be regenerated or not (it should be, if user signed in using normal path)
        /// </summary>
        private static bool CheckIfUserWasSignedInFromRememberMeToken(IOwinContext ctx)
        {
            bool signedInFromRememberMeToken = ctx.Get<bool>("SignedInFromRememberMeToken");

            return signedInFromRememberMeToken;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Generates serializable collection of user claims, that will be saved inside the cookie token. Custom class is used because Claim class causes 'Circular Reference Exception.'
        /// </summary>
        private static List<SerializableClaim> GenerateSerializableClaimListFromIdentity(ClaimsIdentity identity)
        {
            var dataToReturn = identity.Claims.Select(x =>
                                new SerializableClaim()
                                {
                                    Type = x.Type,
                                    ValueType = x.ValueType,
                                    Value = x.Value
                                }).ToList();

            return dataToReturn;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Generates a special claim containing an expiration date of RememberMeToken cookie. This is necessary because we CANNOT rely on browsers here - since each one threat cookies differently
        /// </summary>
        private static SerializableClaim GenerateRememberMeTokenExpirationDateClaim()
        {
            SerializableClaim cookieExpirationDate = new SerializableClaim()
            {
                Type = "RememberMeTokenExpirationDate",
                Value = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(RememberMeTokenPeriodOfvalidityInMinutes).ToBinary().ToString()
            };
            return cookieExpirationDate;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Generates token containing user claims. The token is compressed, encrypted using machine key and returned as base64 string - this string will be saved inside RememberMeToken cookie
        /// </summary>
        private static string GenerateProtectedAndBase64EncodedClaimsToken(List<SerializableClaim> claimsToAdd)
        {
            var allClaimsAsString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(claimsToAdd);

            var allClaimsAsBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(allClaimsAsString);

            var allClaimsAsCompressedBytes = CompressionHelper.CompressDeflate(allClaimsAsBytes);

            var allClaimsAsCompressedBytesProtected = MachineKey.Protect(allClaimsAsCompressedBytes, "RememberMeToken");

            var allClaimsInFinalCompressedAndProtectedBase64Token = Convert.ToBase64String(allClaimsAsCompressedBytesProtected);

            return allClaimsInFinalCompressedAndProtectedBase64Token;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Primary login method
        /// </summary>
        private void Login(IOwinContext context)
        {
            var base64ProtectedCompressedRememberMeTokenBytes = context.Request.Cookies["RememberMeToken"];

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(base64ProtectedCompressedRememberMeTokenBytes))
            {
                var RememberMeToken = GetRememberMeTokenFromData(base64ProtectedCompressedRememberMeTokenBytes);

                var claims = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<SerializableClaim>>(RememberMeToken);

                bool isRememberMeTokenStillValid = IsRememberMeTokenStillValid(claims);

                if (isRememberMeTokenStillValid)
                {
                    //Token is still valid - sign in
                    SignInUser(context, claims);

                    //We set information that user was signed in using the RememberMeToken cookie
                    context.Set("SignedInFromRememberMeToken", true);
                }
                else
                {
                    //Token is invalid or expired - we remove unnecessary cookie
                    context.Response.Cookies.Delete("RememberMeToken");
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// We log user, using passed claims
        /// </summary>
        private void SignInUser(IOwinContext context, IEnumerable<SerializableClaim> claims)
        {
            List<Claim> claimList = new List<Claim>();

            foreach (var item in claims)
            {
                string type = item.Type;

                string value = item.Value;

                claimList.Add(new Claim(type, value));
            }

            ClaimsIdentity ci = new ClaimsIdentity(claimList, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

            context.Authentication.SignIn(ci);

            context.Authentication.User = context.Authentication.AuthenticationResponseGrant.Principal;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get information if RememberMeToken cookie is still valid (checks not only the date, but also some additional information)
        /// </summary>
        private bool IsRememberMeTokenStillValid(IEnumerable<SerializableClaim> claims)
        {
            var userIdClaim = claims.Where(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).SingleOrDefault();

            if (userIdClaim == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("RememberMeTokenAuthMiddleware. Claim of type NameIdentifier was not found.");
            }

            var userSecurityStampClaim = claims.Where(x => x.Type == "AspNet.Identity.SecurityStamp").SingleOrDefault();

            if (userSecurityStampClaim == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("RememberMeTokenAuthMiddleware. Claim of type SecurityStamp was not found.");
            }

            string userId = userIdClaim.Value;

            var userManager = Context.GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();

            if (userManager == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("RememberMeTokenAuthMiddleware. Unable to get UserManager");
            }

            var currentUserData = userManager.FindById(userId);

            if (currentUserData == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (currentUserData.LockoutEndDateUtc >=  DateTime.Now)
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (currentUserData.SecurityStamp != userSecurityStampClaim.Value)
            {
                //User Securitystamp was changed

                return false;
            }

            return GetRememberMeTokenExpirationMinutesLeft(claims) > 0;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns how many minutes the RememberMeToken will be valid - if it expired, returns zero or negative value
        /// </summary>
        private double GetRememberMeTokenExpirationMinutesLeft(IEnumerable<SerializableClaim> claims)
        {
            double dataToReturn = -1;

            var RememberMeTokenExpirationDate = GetRememberMeTokenExpirationDate(claims);

            dataToReturn = (RememberMeTokenExpirationDate - DateTime.Now).TotalMinutes;

            return dataToReturn;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns a DateTime object containing the expiration date of the RememberMeToken
        /// </summary>
        private DateTime GetRememberMeTokenExpirationDate(IEnumerable<SerializableClaim> claims)
        {
            DateTime RememberMeTokenExpirationDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);

            var RememberMeTokenExpirationClaim = GetRememberMeTokenExpirationDateClaim(claims);

            if (RememberMeTokenExpirationClaim == null)
            {
                throw new Exception("RememberMeTokenAuthMiddleware. RememberMeTokenExpirationClaim was not found.");
            }

            long binaryTime = Convert.ToInt64(RememberMeTokenExpirationClaim.Value);

            RememberMeTokenExpirationDate = DateTime.FromBinary(binaryTime);

            return RememberMeTokenExpirationDate;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the claim determining the expiration date of the token
        /// </summary>
        private SerializableClaim GetRememberMeTokenExpirationDateClaim(IEnumerable<SerializableClaim> claims)
        {
            var RememberMeTokenExpirationClaim = claims.Where(x => x.Type == "RememberMeTokenExpirationDate").SingleOrDefault();

            return RememberMeTokenExpirationClaim;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Attempts to decipher the RememberMeToken to the JSON format containing claims
        /// </summary>
        private string GetRememberMeTokenFromData(string base64ProtectedCompressedRememberMeTokenBytes)
        {
            var protectedCompressedRememberMeTokenBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64ProtectedCompressedRememberMeTokenBytes);

            var compressedRememberMeTokenBytes = MachineKey.Unprotect(protectedCompressedRememberMeTokenBytes, "RememberMeToken");

            var RememberMeTokenBytes = CompressionHelper.DecompressDeflate(compressedRememberMeTokenBytes);

            var RememberMeToken = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(RememberMeTokenBytes);

            return RememberMeToken;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns information if token cookie should be delated (for example, when user click 'Logout')
        /// </summary>
        private bool CheckIfRememberMeTokenShouldBeDeleted(IOwinContext context)
        {
            bool shouldDeleteRememberMeToken = (context.Request.Cookies.Where(x => x.Key == "RemoveRememberMeToken").Count() > 0);

            return shouldDeleteRememberMeToken;
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

And some helper classes:
**CompressionHelper.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebApplicationtoRemove.Owin.HelperClasses
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Data compression helper
    /// </summary>
    public static class CompressionHelper
    {
        public static byte[] CompressDeflate(byte[] data)
        {
            MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream();
            using (DeflateStream dstream = new DeflateStream(output, CompressionLevel.Optimal))
            {
                dstream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            }
            return output.ToArray();
        }

        public static byte[] DecompressDeflate(byte[] data)
        {
            MemoryStream input = new MemoryStream(data);
            MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream();
            using (DeflateStream dstream = new DeflateStream(input, CompressionMode.Decompress))
            {
                dstream.CopyTo(output);
            }
            return output.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

**SerializableClaim.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace WebApplicationtoRemove.Owin.HelperClasses
{
    public class SerializableClaim
    {
        public string Type { get; set; }

        public string ValueType { get; set; }

        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

To test the above - create new MVC 4.6.x project (**authentication mode: Individual User Accounts**), add the above classes to it and then modify the **Startup.Auth.cs:**

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google;
using Owin;
using WebApplicationtoRemove.Models;
using WebApplicationtoRemove.Owin.Middleware;

namespace WebApplicationtoRemove
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        // For more information on configuring authentication, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
            app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
            app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

            // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
            // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
            // Configure the sign in cookie
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
                Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
                {
                    // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                    // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                    OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                        regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager)),

                    OnResponseSignedIn = ctx =>
                    {
                        RememberMeTokenMiddleware.CheckAndCreateRememberMeToken(ctx);
                    },

                    OnResponseSignOut = ctx =>
                    {
                        RememberMeTokenMiddleware.Logout(ctx.OwinContext);
                    }
                }
            });

            app.Use<RememberMeTokenMiddleware>();
        }
    }
}
```

What interests you there are these:

```
OnResponseSignedIn = ctx =>
{
    RememberMeTokenMiddleware.CheckAndCreateRememberMeToken(ctx);
},

OnResponseSignOut = ctx =>
{
    RememberMeTokenMiddleware.Logout(ctx.OwinContext);
}
```

and this line:

```
app.Use<RememberMeTokenMiddleware>();
```

This should enable the middleware. How this works: if the user checks '**Remember me**' checkbox, a **RememberMeToken cookie will be created** (containing all the claims user had during login) alongside the 'AspNet.ApplicationCookie'.

When the session times out, **the middleware will check if the RememberMeToken exists, and is still valid** - if so: it will log in the user seamlessly in background.

Hope this helps anyone.

Comment: I Implemented your solution , unfortunately every time the session ends and the invoke function trys to login, the cookie is deleted in the catch function. Any ideas?

Comment: Error received: Error occurred during a cryptographic operation.

Comment: Turns out the solution to my problem was a missing key in web.config.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25857577/error-occurred-during-a-cryptographic-operation-when-decrypting-forms-cookie

Comment: @Sagi

Glad it worked in the end... although it's a bit odd that you had to define the machineKey manually - as far as I know, if the key is not set in web.config, it is automatically generated - just not added to the config. Unless something changed over the years... May I ask, did you had the error on the server, or on your local machine, and which version if IIS were you using?

Comment: Actually it did not fix the problem, still get a cryptographic error when hosting the app. On localhost (local machine) it works great though :). I am considering removing the cryptography part. In any case thanks a bunch for sharing your code !

Comment: @Sagi Without the crypto part, anybody will be able to just decrypt and modify the cookie (it is just plain text in bas64 after all). Perhaps something really changed in the latest IIS and some additional configuration is required (we use IIS 6.1 - pretty ancient version). One additional thing you may want to try is to regenerating the machine key on server AND clean all cookies from the browser (otherwise you will get the exception, since they were generated with different key). Depending on the browser, I usually go into private mode for testing just to be sure no junk interferes.

Comment: Yes agreed no encryption is a no-no, but I'll take the working middle-ware with no encryption over a not working one at all for now. I don't have access to the IIS machine which is a problem. Thanks !